# Unix alias using function to send parameters run job in background

Tags: shell, sas

Looking to create an alias to run `nohup sas myscript.sas -work /mywork/TMP/ &`. My script.sas is a parameter to pass and need to get exit code for script run and need to run myscript.sas in background. Command using is `zz myscript.sas`. Needed `nohup sas myscript.sas -work /mywork/TMP/ &`. Once done need exit code for myscript.sas. Code using is below

```
alias zz='function cmd(){ nohup sas $1 -work /mywork/TMP/ & ; echo "$1 exit: "$? ; };cmd'
```

Comment: Why would you build an alias that defines and then runs a function, instead of _just defining a function_? What purpose does the alias serve?

Comment: That said, when you run something in the background with `&`, you _don't have_ its exit status. Exit status only exists after something has exited, and it's only read by the parent process after it calls `wait()` or `waitpid()`.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want your code to keep running long enough to get the exit status, just leave out the `&` (and the `nohup`), and you'll have that. If you "need" them... well, it'd do a lot of good to explain why, because as-written your stated requirements conflict with each other.

Comment: (also, `nohup` is basically never a good choice of tool; it does _absolutely nothing_ that bash can't do itself using only builtins. `sas "$1" -work /mywork/TMP </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 & disown -h`, and you just did _exactly_ the same thing as `nohup sas "$1" -work /mywork/TMP &` (assuming that stdout and stderr started out going to a TTY), but more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you Charles I will try